# Duplicate Match Count in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am new to MS Excel. I stuck in one problem,
following is the detail description.
I want to find matching rows(cells) from 6 columns and give count in the last column. I have one `Key Column` and six `Haystack` columns to search for. If a key found in any of the haystack column then increment last `Count` column (in front of respective `Key Column`) by +1 and so on. 
For e.g:

```
Heystack 1   Heystack 2   Heystack 3   Heystack 4   Heystack 5   Heystack 6   Key Column   Count Column
A            D            E            C            F            G            A            2
K            E            A            F            W            Z            E            2
C            Q            R            T            N            B            B            1
```

Kindly let me know if i can use any formula for `Count Column`
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try using `COUNTIF`.

Comment: In your count column (cell H2 based on your provided sample data), use this formula and copy down: `=COUNTIF($A$2:$F$4,G2)`  Adjust ranges to suit.  Here's a [link](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) to more information on the COUNTIF function.

Comment: @BigBen Noted that, But how to use COUNTIF() for Haystack1 to Haystack6 at once. Can you give little example.

Comment: See @tigeravatar's comment.

Comment: @tigeravatar It works ! Thanks a lot, Is it possible to color Key column in Red where Count is greater than 1

Comment: That is a separate question, but yes it's possible.  Look into Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Noted, Thanks a lot